# Django pickle.dumps(model.query) hitting db

Tags: python, django

I try to pickle django Query object to save it in Redis.

```
materials = Material.objects.prefetch_related('tags_applied').prefetch_related('materialdata_set').prefetch_related('source')
materials_ids = MaterialData.objects.filter(tag_id__in=tags).values_list('material_id', flat=True)
materials = materials.filter(pk__in=materials_ids)
key_name = SAMPLES_UUID + ':' + str(redis_uuid)
redis_cl.set_key(key_name, pickle.dumps(materials.query))
redis_cl.expire(key_name, SAMPLES_TIMEOUT)
```

Here is the trace from debug_panel(i use lazy pagination):
Source query is:

> SELECT "san_material"."id", "san_material"."created_at",
>   "san_material"."title", "san_material"."author", "san_material"."url",
>   "san_material"."publication_datetime", "san_material"."text",
>   "san_material"."size", "san_material"."source_id",
>   "san_material"."material_type", "san_material"."updated_at",
>   "san_material"."status", "san_material"."elastic_sync",
>   "san_material"."tokens", "san_material"."detection_datetime",
>   "san_material"."article_title",
>   "san_material"."publication_datetime_article",
>   "san_material"."author_article", "san_material"."highlight_data" FROM
>   "san_material" WHERE ("san_material"."detection_datetime" BETWEEN
>   '2016-07-01T00:00:00+03:00'::timestamptz AND
>   '2016-07-27T10:39:00+03:00'::timestamptz AND "san_material"."id" IN
>   (SELECT U0."material_id" FROM "san_materialdata" U0 WHERE U0."tag_id"
>   IN (660))) ORDER BY "san_material"."detection_datetime" DESC LIMIT 51

But it is subquery hits db:

> SELECT U0."material_id" FROM "san_materialdata" U0 WHERE U0."tag_id"
>   IN (660)

in here:

```
/home/maxx/analize/san/utils.py in wrapper(82)
  result = method_to_decorate(*args, **kwds)
/home/maxx/analize/san/views/flux.py in flux(111)
  redis_cl.set_key(key_name, pickle.dumps(materials.query))
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in dumps(1393)
  Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in dump(225)
  self.save(obj)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save(333)
  self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save_reduce(421)
  save(state)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save(288)
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save_dict(657)
  self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(675)
  save(v)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save(333)
  self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save_reduce(421)
  save(state)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save(288)
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save_dict(657)
  self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(675)
  save(v)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save(288)
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save_list(604)
  self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in _batch_appends(620)
  save(x)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save(333)
  self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save_reduce(421)
  save(state)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save(288)
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save_dict(657)
  self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(675)
  save(v)
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py in save(308)
  rv = reduce(self.proto)
/home/maxx/venv/analize/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py in _reduce_ex(84)
  dict = getstate()
```

How can i fix it?

p.s i measured time saving argument in def _batch_setitems:

```
('Save obj time:', 2.5215649604797363, 'arg:', 'rhs')
('Save obj time:', 2.5219039916992188, 'arg:', 'children')
('Save obj time:', 2.5219550132751465, 'arg:', 'where')
```

Its 3 times by 2.5 secs. Why?

Comment: Are you using `django-taggit` or a similar app for managing your tags? I've had a similar problem when dumping a model with tags in JSON. What happened is that each time a tag was dumped, the way it was implemented generated a query. I'm not sure how to do it with pickle, but in the end, I had to replace tags by `[tag.name for tag in mymodel.tags.all()]` when building my JSON.

Comment: OK. What is it exactly that you wish to save into redis? If you're pickling a whole queryset, you'll be preserving the internals of how the queryset is constructed and may have compatibility issues (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets ). If you only want to save the data, it may be better to use serialization instead of pickling: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/

Comment: I am picking only Query objects:
pickle.dumps(materials.query)

Answer (score 1):

Django query's are lazy query's, but let me explain what you have written:

```
materials = Material.objects.prefetch_related('tags_applied'
    ).prefetch_related('materialdata_set').prefetch_related('source')


materials_ids = MaterialData.objects.filter(tag_id__in=tags).values_list('material_id', flat=True)

# till now materials_id is queryset, means it will not hit DB.
# as soon it execute next line of code it will hit db, because in next line you are using materials_ids. 

materials = materials.filter(pk__in=materials_ids)

# So you can avoid hiting db if you are not required to use materials 
key_name = SAMPLES_UUID + ':' + str(redis_uuid)
redis_cl.set_key(key_name, pickle.dumps(materials.query))
redis_cl.expire(key_name, SAMPLES_TIMEOUT)
```

You can correct this by using proper joins in django:

I guess you **MaterialData** model has **material** as foreign key to **Material** model.

```
materials = MaterialData.objects.filter(tag_id__in=tags).prefetch_related(
'material__tags_applied'
).prefetch_related('material__materialdata_set').prefetch_related('material__source').values(*all values realted to mateials you can put here by adding materials__ before each material field *)

# to fetch foreign key attribue you use field followed by duble underscore

key_name = SAMPLES_UUID + ':' + str(redis_uuid)
redis_cl.set_key(key_name, pickle.dumps(materials.query))
```

Comment: Its the same. Does not help

Comment: Subqueries are generally not evaluated when you pass them to `.filter()`. `material_ids` is embedded in `materials` as a subquery, it is not evaluated on its own. It may be evaluated because of some interaction with pickling, but that would evaluate it on `pickle.dumps()`, not when it is passed to `.filter()`.